# Understanding Maven pluginManagement section

Tags: maven

I understand the [pluginManagement](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) section is typically found in a parent `pom.xml` to define common configuration across a project. Child modules can choose to override it if they want much like classic  inheritance in OOP.

But if we look at [this](https://github.com/knowm/XChart/blob/develop/pom.xml) `pom.xml` as example, it does not contain any `pluginManagement` section and instead defines `plugins` under `build -> plugins`.

Question: what is the difference if any between:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
```

and

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
```

On [this](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management) page I found following documentation:

> If your POM declares a parent, it inherits plugin configuration from either the build/plugins or pluginManagement sections of the parent.

Questions:

1. What happens if I define BOTH build/plugins and pluginManagement in parent `pom.xml` and there is inconsistency between the two? e.g., in build/plugins I define a plugin foo with version X and in pluginManagement I define plugin foo with version Y and further with different configuration?
2. Is the intention (best practice) to use one of build/plugins or pluginManagement but not both?
3. What purpose does adding two ways to achieve the same thing accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is worth to dive into that rabbit hole... Let's try...

When we are talking about maven plugin configurations we are actually interested in the following:

- what plugin goals will be invoked
- what is the actual configuration of those goals

The best and the only answer for those questions is the following:

> You need to run `mvn help:effective-pom` and analyse the result

However, I do believe that is not kind of answer you have expected.

Maven is using following strategy for merging plugin configurations:

- parent `plugins` element gets merged into child `plugins` element
- parent `pluginManagement` element gets merged into child `pluginManagement` element
- resulting child `pluginManagement.plugins` element get merged into child `plugins` element
- resulting child `plugins` element gets expanded, i.e. resulting `plugin.configuration` element gets merged into resulting `plugin.executions.execution.configuration` element

based on the strategy, described above, I would say the usage of `pluginManagement` section is definitely superfluous and, moreover, it complicates a lot of things, below are some other arguments in favour of not using `pluginManagement`:

- IDEs (here I can speak for `IntellyJ` only) do not recognise `pluginManagement` section as a source of plugins you may execute outside of build lifecycle, e.g. if my goal is to periodically execute [owasp's `dependency-check:aggregate`](https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/dependency-check-maven/aggregate-mojo.html) I need to either define it in `build.plugins` (otherwise `IntellyJ` does not recognise it) or execute it via `terminal` window, which is very inconvenient (`IntellyJ` does not support execution identifiers as well, however that is another story).
- the most of modern maven plugins do support `<skip>` configuration element, and due to that we may control execution of particular maven plugin via `properties` section instead of writing those verbose XMLs, moreover, that (the existence of `<skip>` configuration in modern plugins) proves the whole idea of configuring plugins via `pluginManagement` and then defining plugins in `build.plugins` was wrong

for example, if particular plugin supports `<skip>` configuration that is more convenient to define it using following way:

```xml
<properties>
  <!-- 
   here I would actually prefer something 
   based on pom packaging
  --> 
  <skip.javadoc>false</skip.javadoc>
</properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach_docs</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <skip>${skip.javadoc}</skip>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

or even:

```xml
<properties>
  <skip.javadoc>false</skip.javadoc>
</properties>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach_docs</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <skip>${skip.javadoc}</skip>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

rather than:

```xml
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.javadoc.plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach_docs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>

  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```